# print out just one order number and the items associated with that number

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a mysql table holding the items from my cart array, e.g. item_id, size, quantity and they also have an order number in each row so if i had 3 items, the three rows would have the order id of 2. There is another table called orders which holds the order number for those items and the name, address etc. I want to be able to print out each order number and the items that match that order number however it's repeating the order number and printing it out three times, is there anyway i can just have order number: 1 then the three items below this?

This query does print out the correct information but displays the orderid 3 times

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT transactions.*, orders.orderid, orders.date  
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN orders
ON transactions.orderid=orders.orderid
WHERE orders.userid = '$userID'");
```

Comment: The query doesn't need to be changed... the code that loops through the resultset (which you haven't shown here) does... you need to put a test in that loop code, and only display the orderid when it actually changes

Comment: any idea how i can write an if statment to check if orderid has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on FlyingFoX's example

```
$currentOrderId = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
    if ($currentOrderId != $row["orderid"]){ 
        // put everything that shall only be written once here. 
        echo $row["orderid"]; 
        $currentOrderId = $row["orderid"]; 
    } 
    // put everything that shall be written for every row here. 
    echo $row["date"]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been plaguing me for a while now, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query isn't technically displaying anything at all. It just queries your data from your database and makes it locally accessible to do with it what you want.
So the point where you actually have to change stuff is at your displaying code. It can look like the following to work as you intended.

```
first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    if (first){
        // put everything that shall only be written once here.
        echo $row["orderid"];
        first = false;
    }
    // put everything that shall be written for every row here.
    echo $row["date"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, although it's not showing the next order number after that, only number 3 when the user has two orders number 3 and 4